# dpkg-reconfigure on CentOS (for openssh_server)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, rpm, apt

Systems that use the `apt` packaging system have access to a command called `dpkg-reconfigure` which, depending on the package, re-runs some setup commands.

At least on Ubuntu, it's possible to regenerate the SSH daemon keys in one shot by removing them from `/etc/ssh`, and running `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`. This causes the first-time setup that normally builds the keys when the daemon is installed to be reinvoked. A very handy shortcut when doing automated installs!

Now, I understand that all that this process is doing is a number of `ssh-keygen` commands in the background, but that's not what I'm asking here. What I want to know is: **Is there an equivalent one-shot command on RPM based systems like CentOS to do the same reconfiguration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS is using RPM and might trigger post/pre-update/install scripts. But as your mentioned example for `sshd`, we use `sshd-keygen` service, which takes care of key generation during first start (and basically checks if the keys are in place before each start/restart of `sshd` daemon.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* -f && systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).